# Java storing and getting from class

Tags: java, class, object

Is it possible to get values from the class based one one value? Something very much like a SQL WHERE statement.

class :

```
private String aid;
public String text;
public class B{
    public B(String a){
        this.aid = a;
    }
    public B(String a, String c)
    {
        this.aid = a;
        this.cid = c;
    }
    /** getter setter here **/
```

And from another file, I would like to retrieve the data from this class with the value of aid = "John"

Comment: No.............

Comment: If you have a List yes.

Answer (score 1):

There might be libraries out there that provide such a functionality with a query language in place but with the standard feature set of a JVM, `Streams` should come the closest to what you look for:

Assuming a `List` containing your POJOs you can do the following to get a new `List` of entries with the "John" as value for `aid`:

```
List<B> entries = getSourceList();
List<B> filteredEntries = entries.stream()
    .filter(elem -> String.valueOf(elem.getAid()).equals("John"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Sorry but where does getSourceList come from

Comment: @user9370081 It's an example method that produces a list containing objects of type B. He/She is demonstrating how to use the java 8 Streams API which is super powerful with handling collections of objects and primitives.